# Python - printing out through json objects using for loop

Tags: python, json, for-loop

So I have been playing around to make a sort of monitor - What monitor is that it prints out whenever a new item, object, number is new, then print it out basically nothing harm.

The json I am printing out (I know this is not a correctly json format now but it does print out the correctly stuff currently)

```
"threads": {
    "1": {
        "name": "Hello",
        "id": "4174"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "World",
        "id": "6231"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Overflow",
        "id": "7231"
    }
}
```

---

Basically I have done a script that right now:

```
def get_feed():

    url = 'https://www.helloworld.com/loadfilter'
    resp = s.get(url, timeout=6)
    resp.raise_for_status()

    return resp.json()['threads']

old_list = []

for index, thread in get_feed().items():
    old_list.append(thread['id'])

while True:
    try:

        new_list = []
        for index, thread in get_feed().items():
            new_list.append(thread['id'])

        for index, item in enumerate(new_list):
            if item in old_list:
                print(item['name'] # ERROR - string indices must be integers

        else:
            print('Sleeping 2 sec')
            time.sleep(2)


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


sys.exit()
```

So basically if I print out inside the `for index, thread in get_feed().items():` a print of `thread['name']` that would be not an issue and it would print it out.

However in the for loop of: `if item in old_list:`  - The issue there is it does not print out anything but the id numbers that I have added to the list and I wonder how can I possible make it so it prints out the names through the json that is given above?

Meaning : whenever I print out after the `if item old list` etc. item['name'] it should give the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you create `old_list` you are only appending the `id` of each `thread`, rather than the thread itself. If you want to be able to print the `name` of the `thread`, you'll need to put each `thread` object in `old_list`. You should also do the same thing in creating `new_list` in order for everything to match up.

Here's how you can do this:

Creating `old_list` (note there's no need to use a `for` loop to get the values out of a dictionary):

```
old_list = list(get_feed().values())
```

Creating `new_list`:

```
new_list = list(get_feed().values())
```

Checking/printing:

```
for thread in new_list:
    if thread in old_list:
        print(thread['name'])
```

Comment: Oh you are very true! This help me alot and I can confirm that this was the solution, so well as pekapa under was good said aswell! thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1):

Your `item` is just the `thread['id']` and that's why you can't access the `name` anymore.
You could try saving the whole thread object in your lists and not just the `id`

For instance:

```
for index, thread in get_feed().items():
    new_list.append(thread)
```

or, as suggested in @henry's answer, without the loop:

```
new_list = list(get_feed().values())
```

And than you can compare if `item['id']` is in the `old_list` and than `print (item['name'])` would work because you'd have the whole `thread` object.

(Edit: note that, here, we are only checking the `id`, if you go back to @henry's suggestion, you would check the whole `thread`, including every attribute that it might have)